# How can I open a process with its PID in pymem

Tags: python, pid

I have managed to change some bytes in a game by using pymem library. I made it by searching process name. But now I need to do it with its PID. Here is my code:

```
def pattern_scan_all(handle, pattern, *, return_multiple=False):
    next_region = 0
    found = []
    while next_region < 0x7FFFFFFF0000:
        next_region, page_found = pymem.pattern.scan_pattern_page(
            handle,
            next_region,
            pattern,
            return_multiple=return_multiple
        )
        if not return_multiple and page_found:
            return page_found
        if page_found:
            found += page_found

    if not return_multiple:
        return None
    return found


pm = pymem.Pymem("Game.exe")
bytes_pattern_MaxEXP = b"\\x20\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x36"
allLevel_maxExp_addrs = pattern_scan_all(pm.process_handle, bytes_pattern_MaxEXP, return_multiple=True)

for addr in allLevel_maxExp_addrs:    
    work.addr = addr
    break
```

Nowadays the game is working on web browser and i need to access it by using its PID, Is there any way of accessing it by using its PID.

Thanks for your time.
"

I tried "pm = pymem.Pymem.open_process_from_id(9812)" but it gives me "TypeError: Pymem.open_process_from_id() missing 1 required positional argument: 'process_id'" error.

Answer (score 1):

you probably want to learn oop in python.

The open_process_from_id function is an attribute of the Pymem object in Python. This function is used to open a process using its process ID (PID).

Here is a simple example of how to use this function:

```py
pm = pymem.Pymem()
pm.open_process_from_id(PID)
```

in this example the pm is an object of [Pymem](https://pymem.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#pymem.Pymem) class and the [open_process_from_id](https://pymem.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#pymem.Pymem.open_process_from_id) is a method of this class. which we call to open the process using its unique identifier